# Convert a directive to use isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a simple directive but at the moment i don't have any scope set. However i want the directive to use isolated scope so that i can easily reuse it.

This is my html and the directive is called "select-time":

```
<div class="menuHour after" select-time><div class="menuHour-panel before"><span class="menuHour-panel-title" ng-click="changeToBefore()">Before 12h</span></div>
```

I have kept the example short so the only thing it's doing here is changing the class "menuHour after" to "menuHour before".

It's doing that with a method "changeToBefore()".

This is my directive:

```
angular.module("tiki").directive("selectTime", function(newTiki){

return {

    restrict:"A",
    controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){

        $scope.changeToBefore = function(){

            var menuHour = document.querySelector(".menuHour")

            menuHour.classList.remove("after")
            menuHour.classList.add("before")

        }

    }

}
```

})

How can i change this to an isolated scope directive?

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with `scope: {}`:

I would also use $element instead of getting the element again!

```
angular.module("tiki").directive("selectTime", function(newTiki){

  return {

      restrict:"A",
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: '/path/to/directive.html',
      controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){

        $scope.changeToBefore = function(){

            $element.removeClass("after")
            $element.addClass("before")

        }

      }

  }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work, i think it's because the html code is not in a template (templateUrl: ... or template: "..") no?

Comment: fyi, you mis-spelled $element

Comment: Ok, just tried it out and indeed you have to create a templateUrl and link to the template for the isolated scope to work. To bad though, because now i have another http request that i think should not be needed.

Comment: you can also define your HTML with ``template`` inside the directive code, instead of using ``tempalteUrl``

Comment: Yes, but that's not very fun if you have to change the html, especially if you have a big directive.

Comment: Betty, if you change your answer to include the templateUrl property on the directive definition object then i will set it as correct answer...